# Showing multiple previews in Xcode 15 and up using Preview Macro

Tags: xcode, preview, xcode15

How can I show two or more different variants in Xcode using the new `#Preview` macro?

Without the macro, this was possible:

```
struct TutorialView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyAwesomeView(title: "Title One", hideSomePart: true)
            .previewDisplayName("Hidden some part")
        
        MyAwesomeView(title: "Title Two", hideSomePart: false)
            .previewDisplayName("Showing all parts")
    }
}
```

But with the new macro, this isn't compiling:

```
#Preview {
    MyAwesomeView(title: "Title One", hideSomePart: true)
        .previewDisplayName("Hidden some part")
        
    MyAwesomeView(title: "Title Two", hideSomePart: false)
        .previewDisplayName("Showing all parts")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using .previewDisplayName("...") does not work for me. I got it working doing it like this:

```
#Preview("Hidden some part") {
  MyAwesomeView(title: "Title One", hideSomePart: true)
}

#Preview("Showing all parts") {   
  MyAwesomeView(title: "Title Two", hideSomePart: false)
}
```

Comment: See [previewDisplayName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/previewdisplayname(_:)) documentation -- should work on iOS 13.0+

Comment: It should but I didn't. They way I got it working was as I showed on my example.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a simple fix:

```
#Preview {
    MyAwesomeView(title: "Title One", hideSomePart: true)
        .previewDisplayName("Hidden some part")
}

#Preview {   
    MyAwesomeView(title: "Title Two", hideSomePart: false)
        .previewDisplayName("Showing all parts")
}
```